# Managed ISAPI Filter IIS 7.5

Tags: caching, iis-7.5, httphandler, httpmodule, isapi

Is there any way to write ISAPI Filter functionality in Managed Code (C#) for IIS 7.5?
In detail, I need access to the Requests Response Stream, before it is actually sent back to the client to implement some caching functionality.
Via HttpModule or HttpHandler I only find methods like BeginRequest or ProcessRequest...

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a send_raw_data filter, and just to warn you, those carry a significant performance penalty. It may be enough to offset the benefit of caching, so you should keep that in mind.

I don't know of a way to do this with managed code, other than maybe calling it through some sort of C++ wrapper, but this is a very perf-sensitive code path, so I wouldn't recommend it. ISAPI is designed for C/C++ and you should use it that way.